# Find linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

How's the standard way to solve this kind of problems?

> Find a linear transformation $T:R^4 \rightarrow R^4$ such that 
>   $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\2\\0\\2 \end{pmatrix}\in R(T)$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}\in R(T)$ and $T ∘ T$ is the zero transformation.

**Attemp to solve**

What I try to find is a matrix $A$ such that $T(x)=A\cdot x$. Because T goes from $R^4$ to $R^4$, $A\in R^{4x4}$. Given that $(1,2,0,2)^t$ and $(1,1,0,0)^t$ are in the range of T, they also are in the column space of $A$. Because $T ∘ T$ is the zero transformation, $T\begin{pmatrix} 1\\2\\0\\2 \end{pmatrix}=A\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1\\2\\0\\2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $T\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}=A\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$

Well, I don't know what to do next. I could try find the components $a_{ij}$ of A by solving a system of equations, but (if it works) I don't think that is the way we solve this kind of problems.

Comment: Your idea to solve for the entries of $A$ is a good one; the only missing thing is that you haven't attached any conditions to make sure that the given vectors are in the column space of $A$.  Probably the easiest way to ensure that is just to put those given vectors in $A$ as columns (and leave the other two columns as to-be-solved-for).

Answer (score 2):

**Remark:** The linear transformation $T$ isn't unique.

Let's denote  $v_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\2\\0\\2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$. By the hypothesis $T^2=0$ we have $R(T)\subset \ker(T)$. Let $B_c=(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$ the standard basis of $\Bbb R^4$ and since $B=(v_1,v_2,e_3,e_4)$ is also a basis of $\Bbb R^4$ so let's define $T$ in this manner:
$$T(v_1)=0\quad;\quad T(v_2)=0\quad; T(e_3)=v_1\quad;\quad T(e_4)=v_2$$
and if we denote $P$ the change matrix from $B_c$ to $B$ then we have
$$[T]_{B_c}=P[T]_BP^{-1}$$
hence we find
$$T(x,y,z,t)=(t+2x-2y+z,t+2x-2y+2z,0,2z)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Say that $f_1,\ldots,f_4$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$. What does the mapping generated by
$$
T(f_1)=f_3,\qquad T(f_2)=f_4,\qquad T(f_3)=\vec{0},\qquad T(f_4)=\vec{0}
$$
look like?

Answer (score 1):

Since  $T^2=0$ then following your notation $R(T)\subset \ker T$ hence the vectors you gave  are mapped to $0$. Take $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^4$. The linear map $T$ is completely caracterised by giving the images of the basis elements. The vectors you gave are $u=e_1+e_2$ and $v=e_1+2e_2+2e_4$ then  by linearity: 
$$T(e_1)+T(e_2)=0\implies T(e_2)=-T(e_1)$$
and 
$$T(e_1)+2T(e_2)+2T(e_4)=0\implies T(e_4)=\dfrac{1}{2}T(e_1)$$
Now it suffices to choose 
$$T(e_1)=e_3$$
and 
$$T(e_3)=0$$
In conclusion we can choose $T$ such that 
$$T(e_1)=e_3;\;T(e_2)=-e_3;\;T(e_3)=0;\; T(e_4)=\dfrac{1}{2}e_3$$